# How to scale and loadtest a nuxt.js and express application?

Tags: express, redis, socket.io, nuxt.js, scaling

**Application Summary:**

I have a multiplayer gaming platform built on Nuxt.js with an express backend. I am using MongoDB (Mongoose ORM), Socket.io and Redis (for caching).

I am using a REST API for accessing and modifying game and user data, and socketio for propagating updates to connected users for games - such as when a user interacts with one of the games and the other connected users need to see the updated state. I am using redis for caching expensive computations such as showing a top 10 leaderboard, and then continuously updating the cache with mongodb change streams.

The current structure is monolithic. Everything is sat on a single contained node/nuxt application.

**Problems Experienced:**

During a small beta, I had an influx of about 30-50 users. After about 30 minutes heavy lag was experienced. Web socket events would sometimes be completely missed by the server/client and or they would take more than 10-15 seconds to be received by the client, and certain get/post requests would take 10 seconds+ to go through.

I have 0 experience with scaling. Any info would be appreciated.

**Request:**

- What would be an effective way to scale this application. Would I need to change anything about the structure in order to scale it? Would I need to use certain technologies like docker, things like load balancing ect..
- How can I load test the application for both the end points and websockets? I currently don't know how many users my application can handle?

**TLDR;**

Nuxt.js application using: Express.js, Socket.io, Redis and MongoDB.
How can I scale this application and load test so I can see exactly how many users my application can handle before I need to add more resources/instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you biggest bottleneck (it very well could be a code issue too but this may be low hanging fruit, and in general best to design for scale) is trying to run everything on the same server (Unless I'm not understanding correctly but that's what it sounds like

> Everything is sat on a single contained node/nuxt application

With that assumption each of your applications should be placed on their own server so, as an example

Note: If you are not familiar with managing these services then I would probably look for a managed type solution

1. Redis server for caching X 1
2. Mongo server for DB X 1

DB and Redis are usually very performant so a single instance should be fine to start, not to say a cluster would not be needed but right now you should be ok

Now for the application stack you are going to want to break out each app to its own server, what this means is

1. Game (express)
2. Socket.IO
3. Rest API?

Should all be separate application, each capable of using the full CPU, without having to compete with other processes.

In you post you mentioned things started to slow down and lag, this could simply be the eventloop is backed up, Node ( single threaded ) will process in order of the request so if that keeps filling up, well things will take longer to process.

Now, you mentioned how you would do this, and well that is a big question and depending on who you ask you will get different answers, and the 'right' solution is going to depend on how much you want to manage and how comfortable you are with each technology. For example, you mentioned containers.. Containers are great! but if you are not familiar with Docker and Kuberneties and the concepts in general it can be a challenge and if you are a one man shop, well thats even more work..

So, as I'm sure cost is a factor because, well it always is but luckily its not too expensive to start..

Personally I use multiple servers and services from AWS, Linode and Digital Ocean (100.00 free credit), I like Digital Ocean (even though some dont, I have not had issues with them so I will talk in terms of using them)

Now getting started, you can always spin up multiple 'Droplets' and use PM2 to take full advantage of each CPU for each application, this works but you still need to add a load balancer etc, and to scale horizontally you need to provision new servers, configure and add them to the clusters, again this will work but its more work.

Digital Ocean does offer a service call 'Apps' that is basically a CAAS offering, that allows you to deploy from GIT to a container, letting you scale out horizontally very quickly, I use this service for my socket.io services.. When I know I'm going to have a heavy load, I just add a few more 'apps' to my socket server and scale from 2 to 6 servers in a few min, then when I'm not I scale it down..

So my TLDR is, break everything apart, you don't want to have apps competing for resources

*** Edit ***

Just to add to this, as  @kissu mentioned, you can for sure use Heroku, very similar to DO Apps however (my personal experience here) they can be a bit more expensive but with auto scaling (DO Apps does not offer that). For me I know when I'll experience spikes so its easy for me to plan but with a game autoscaling may be something to look at or consider. In that case Heroku OR AWS may work better (AWS with Auto Scale groups with custom AMIs for your app)

Comment: Great answer. I'd also add that you can probably have auto-scaling platforms like Heroku does.

Comment: I appreciate such a thorough answer, thank you very much. I've gone the route you've suggested and began separating parts of the application.

Comment: Did you say heavy computation  and the backend is served with Node.js? There’s your bottleneck- the leaderboard. A single node.js server can serve thousands of connections and I can only believe this is a code issue.